# How to ensure HighStocks chart x-axes span the full chart width?

Tags: css, highcharts

The same question was asked at stackoverflow already, but I could not find an answer for that problem.

I have the problem that I need to show two x-axes in the chart. And they shall practically start before the y-axis. I tried already many options with offsets, formatters and many other Highstock configurations, but I could not find a good solution yet.

I now had added two div's (longxaxis1 and longxaxis2), but there I have the issue that the split tooltip at the bottom is overlapped by that div then. The div (longxaxis2) should be completely visible, but behind the tooltip. I tried z-index with value -1 on the div via CSS styles, but it only works if the background-color of the main div is transparent. In my case, it needs to have the background color white.

[image: 2nd custom x-axis overlaps tooltip]
A code example with the problem can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/q4wkht7d/

```
/* CSS */
.main {
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}

.longxaxis1 {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -13.6em;
}

.longxaxis2 {
    background-color: #999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 11.4em;
}

/* Highstock Json config */
...
tooltip: {
      split: true,
      valueDecimals: 2,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      useHTML: true,
      style: {
          zIndex: 2
      }      
},
```

Does anyone know a better solution for that? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a z-index to the main div. It looks like the JS generates the the styles, so you have to add !important here.

```
#container div.highcharts-container {
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vqp8a63z/2/

Comment: That's what I needed. Yes, I thought an important would not be necessary because my style definition was the last. But you are absolutely, right, Highstock defines a lot of styles with JS. The solution can be so simple sometimes. I had tried so many things that I didn't have that in mind anymore. Thanks a lot!